# How to write locator for this element

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, pycharm

I'm running automated UI tests and want to verify that this button is disabled but I'm unsure how to create a locator for this element :

Element Source

```
<a data-hook="loginbutton" 
   class="mb-button mb-button--wider mb-button--primary 
          mb-button--disabled mb-button" tabindex="0">Login</a>
```

I have previously used the `data-hook` attribute for the button but there is only one data-hook for the button even if it is enabled or disabled.

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML, code trials and error you faced.

Comment: Plase kindly share the full DOM of the element

Comment: css locator `a[data-hook="loginbutton"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing -

```
    def login_button_disabled(self):
        self.login_button_disabled = self.browser.find_element_by_class_name("mb-button--disabled")
        if self.login_button_disabled.is_displayed():
            print("Login Button Disabled")
        else:
            print("Login Button Enabled")
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS Selector would be the best fit I think
You could either use:

`find_element_by_css_selector(a[".mb-button.mb-button--wider.mb-button--primary.mb-button--disabled.mb-button"])`

Or this:

`find_element_by_css_selector(a[data-hook="loginbutton"])`

The first one is basically using classes, so it can be shorter, depends on how unique the element's classes are in the web

Comment: Thanks RegCent. I'll give the first suggestion a try, the second suggestion won't work as the same data-hook is used whether the button is enabled or disabled

Comment: Okay, in case it works, please mark it as an answer, otherwise, let me know and I'll try to think of something else

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Xpath  for the above mentioned Element. 
xpath = //a[contains(text(),'Login')]